# If there is no value in a filter then exit sub

Tags: vba, validation, excel, filter

I am running a macro where it filters based on a number that the user has entered. It then takes that number and filters a list based on that value. I need a validation where if a user put in a number that is not on the list it will exit the macro. I think I am close but I am new to VBA so I keep getting stuck. Any help would be awesome!

Thanks!

```
    'Filter based on user entry
Sheets("New Revision ").Select
    part = Range("B4").Value
    Sheets("PN_List").Select
    Columns("D:E").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$3000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=part
    If ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$3000").AutoFilter Field=1, Criteria1="" Then
    MsgBox "Part number not found please try again.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Entry Error"
    Exit Sub
    End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sheets("New Revision ").Select
    part = Range("B4").Value
    Sheets("PN_List").Select
    If Application.Countif([A1:A3000], part)  < 1 Then
    MsgBox "Part number not found please try again.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Entry Error"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    Sheets("PN_List").Columns("D:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$3000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=part
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
Sub Parts()
Dim Part As Variant
Dim Found As Boolean
  Part = Sheets("New Revision").Range("B4").Value
  On Error Resume Next ' If the lookup fails, ignore the error
    ' the following assumes Part is in Column A
    Found = WorksheetFunction.Match(Part, Sheets("PN_List").Range("$A$1:$A$3000"), 0) > 0
  On Error GoTo 0 ' Resume normal error handling
  If Not Found Then
    MsgBox "Part number not found please try again.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Entry Error"
  End If
End Sub
```

Edit: you can still filter if you want that. Maybe a good place to do that is in an `Else` clause of `If Not Found`.

Comment: You could do the same without the need of the extra variable or changing the On Error action. by replaceing everything between Part and Msgbox with `If Not IsError(Application.Match(Part, Range("$A$1:$A$3000"), 0)) Then` you could also get rid of both your dim statements also. would go from 9 lines to 4. As the question is not to find match just if there is one, so you don't need to actually return the result of the match.

Comment: @user2140261 all good points. The value for `Part` can be determined on the fly too, reducing the code even further. I intentionally chose to show a more step-wise approach. That said, I like your use of `CountIf` better than my choice of `Match` (and upvoted for that reason).