# Excel vba can't find date when entered by user

Tags: excel, vba, date, find, inputbox

I'm still somewhat new to VBA and my code worked earlier today but now for some reason it stopped finding the date in my selected column even if it is present.
I'm reading through each row and looking for two criteria (1. date for migration, 2. Network). once done, I copy the rows depending on their criteria to separate worksheets and consequently save them later on. My problem now is that despite the date I enter, it doesn't find it anymore - and I do make sure to enter it in DD/MM/YYYY format as that's my underlying format. Despite what I put it it boots me to Err_Execute.

Here is the kind of data I'm working with:

- ColA PCname (i.e. John's machine)
- ColB User name (i.e. John Doe)
- ColC DeviceType (i.e. laptop)
- ColD Network (i.e. Jody's network)
- ColE Migration wave (i.e. 1st wave)
- ColF Top user of device
- ColG Last person to login
- ColH Location of device
- ColI Migration date (looked up in another workbook so still a formula) ColJ User's email
- ColK SR#
- ColL migration date (copied as value instead of formula)

---

```
Sub test()

Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow1 As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow2 As Integer
Dim LSearchValue As String
On Error GoTo Err_Execute
Sheets("Confirmed devices").Activate
Range("I2:I10000").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("L2:L10000").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets.Add.Name = "Jody"
Sheets.Add.Name = "Jason"
LSearchValue = InputBox("Which migration date do you wish to prepare the    files for?", "The format has to be DD/MM/YYYY.")

LSearchRow = 2
LCopyToRow1 = 1
LCopyToRow2 = 1

While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearhRow)).Value) > 0
If Range("L" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = LSearchValue And Range("D" & CStr  (LSearchRow)).Value = "Jody's network" Then
 Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Jody").Select
 Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow1) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow1)).Select
 Sheets("Jody").Paste
 LCopyToRow1 = LCopyToRow1 + 1
 Sheets("Confirmed devices").Select
 End If
 If Range("L" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = LSearchValue And Range("D" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Jason" Then
     Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
     Selection.Copy
     Sheets("Jason").Select
     Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow2) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow2)).Select
     Sheets("Jason").Paste
    LCopyToRow2 = LCopyToRow2 + 1
     Sheets("Confirmed devices").Select
 End If
 LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1
 Wend

'MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

Exit Sub
 Err_Execute:
 MsgBox "That date was not found."`
```

Any help in finding out why it doesn't find the date anymore would be very much appreciated.

---

The error handeler isn't working though, so despite the value I put for the input (LSearchValue), I still get the msg that all data has been copied.
Other than fixing the typo, I changed my code a little bit in hopes of getting the error handeler to work. Is anyone able to help? Is there perhaps a better way to deal with a value which can't be found in my 'L' column?

```
Sub test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow1 As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow2 As Integer
Dim LSearchValue As String
Dim fname1 As String
Dim fname2 As String
Dim fpath As String
Dim Newbook1 As Workbook
Dim Newbook2 As Workbook

Sheets("Confirmed devices").Activate
Range("I2:I10000").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("L2:L10000").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

LSearchValue = InputBox("Which migration date do you wish to prepare the files for?", "The format has to be DD/MM/YYYY.")
LSearchRow = 2
LCopyToRow1 = 1
LCopyToRow2 = 1
Sheets.Add.Name = "Jodi"
Sheets.Add.Name = "Jason"

 While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0
 If Range("L" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = LSearchValue And Range("D" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Jodi’s Network” Then

 Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select

 Selection.Copy

 Sheets("Jodi").Select

 Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow1) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow1)).Select

 Sheets("Jodi").Paste

 LCopyToRow1 = LCopyToRow1 + 1

 Sheets("Confirmed devices").Select

 ElseIf Range("L" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = LSearchValue And Range("D" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Jason’s Network" Then

 Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select

 Selection.Copy

 Sheets("Jason").Select

 Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow2) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow2)).Select

 Sheets("Jason").Paste

 LCopyToRow2 = LCopyToRow2 + 1

 Sheets("Confirmed devices").Select

 End If
 LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

Wend
 MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

 Exit Sub
 Err_Execute: MsgBox "There are no migrations for this date"

End Sub
```

Comment: In your first While statement, is `LSearhRow` just a typo on this site? Also, have you done any debugging? Comment out the on error statement and see where the error is actually happening (it's probably not a good idea to have the entire block of code surrounded by the error handler, how will you know if something else goes wrong?). Also look into VBA's debugging capabilities. You can put a break point and see what values VBA actually has for variables at any given time.

Comment: Are you trying to create a series of worksheets based on the User Name or the Network. Your hard-coded and redacted vars make it hard to see the point.

Comment: @ mock_blatt: yes it is a typo in the first While statement.
I will try the debugger when I get back to work Monday. If I wanted to move the error handler inside my loops, can I simply move the line? Is it as simple as that?

@ Jeeped: I need to create a worksheet for each network, not user.

Perhaps a fresh look on Monday will allow me to find the problem.
I will update the post when I've made progress.

Comment: I was able to find the link I'd found and adapted for my purpose (http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/search_for_string2.php). The error handeling isn't working for me.

Comment: I'm also looking into this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616522/if-there-is-no-value-in-a-filter-then-exit-sub) to see if I can figure out how to resolve my problem.

Comment: Sorry should have specified as well that fixing the typo made the code work however the error handeler isn't working as I'd like it to.